# Restrict access to PHP files in /lib but allow other files to call them (lighttpd)

Tags: php, web, lighttpd

I am trying to restrict direct access to all php files in the /lib directory, but allow other php scripts in the web server access them (ie AJAX calls). The following restricts access correctly, but prevents other php files from calling them as well:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/lib" {
    url.access-deny = (".php")
}
```

Is there a way to ONLY prevent direct access??

Comment: if you don't want something accessible via the web, then don't put it into your site's document root. PHP is not bound AT ALL by webserver-level restrictions and can access ANY file on the system which its controlling UID has access to.

Comment: With the above code it blocks everything. Even my files that call something in /lib

Comment: not possible, php doing an `include('/lib/...')` is not bound by webserver restrictions. not unless you did it as `include('http://example.com/lib/....')`, which'd be incredibly inefficient and highly insecure.

Comment: I'm using `require_once`

I have an AJAX call that simply displays enabled or disabled that it gets from something in lib. With the above code, it no longer works. I comment it out, it works again.

Comment: then yeah you have to make it publically available. and since it's ajax, you can't even password protect it. you're basically hosed if you need to really keep these files secure.

Comment: It's not crucial, I just don't like the idea of people being able to type lib/example.php and seeing the content. Even if it is something simple like this.

What about using $HTTP["referer"]? Maybe look to see if it is coming from internal? If it is not, restrict access, otherwise allow it?

Comment: referer's not reliable: easy to forge, not always sent, etc... your best bet would be some kind of authentication system, but since it's ajax, the auth tokens/codes would be embedded in your js code anyways.

Comment: Yep. Do you know of a way to see if a request is coming from internally though?

Comment: not reliably. remember that the js code and what it's sending are coming from the user's browser. they can, by definition, see anything the browser's doing and could replicate that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can set the permissions of "lib" to 555 i believe it should block it from the outside world.